# matplotlib 1.3.1 cannot import name subprocess

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running WinPython 3.3.2 and I have just upgraded matplotlib to version 1.3.1. Now I am getting the following message when I try to import matplotlib:

```
In [6]: import matplotlib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-82be63b7783c> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>()
    129 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
    130 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
--> 131 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    132 
    133 try:

ImportError: cannot import name subprocess
```

Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: did you make sure to the old version first?  And is that where you installed it?